# Is there way to use the spread operator to merge two objects such that the result has the keys of one object, but the values of the second?

Tags: javascript, object

I have two js objects.

```
Object1 ={a:'a1',b:'b1'}

Object2 ={b:'b2',c:'c2'}
```

My goal is to use spread operators to create a new object with the keys of Object 1 and the values of Object 2.

Using a normal spread operator merge:

```
newObject = {...Object1,...Object2}
```

The collision will still append all of the keys and values from object 2 onto the resulting object.

```
newObjectWithNormalSpreadoperator = {a:'a1',b:'b2',c:'c2'}
```

I'd like to create a new object that has all of object 1's keys, and object 2's values for shared keys.

```
newObjectThatIWant = {a:'a1',b:'b2'}
```

Is there a means of doing this using spread operators?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)** Keep only shared keys in the second object.

**2)** Then use the spread operator.

```js
let obj1 ={a:'a1',b:'b1'};
let obj2 ={b:'b2',c:'c2'};

let obj2Shared = Object.keys(obj2).reduce((acc, currKey) => {
  if (obj1[currKey]) {
    acc[currKey] = obj2[currKey];
  }
  return acc;
}, {});

let combined = {...obj1, ...obj2Shared};

console.log(combined);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
let Object1 ={a:'a1',b:'b1'}
let Object2 ={b:'b2',c:'c2'}
let newObject = {};
Object.keys(Object1).forEach(key => {
  newObject[key] = typeof Object2[key] != "undefined" ? Object2[key] : Object1[key];
});

console.log(newObject)
```

Comment: That's a slightly better implementation of my current solution. I just wanted to see if there was any sort of built-in way to do this.

Comment: This will fail for e.g. `Object2 = { b:null }` (or any other falsy value). You should simply check if `key` is included in `keys(Object2)` instead of trying to be clever with the `||` operator.

Comment: @sloth I suppose that's true. For my specific application, I'm not concerned with falsy values, but for other applications that might not be the case.

Comment: @sloth  this not will fail, because `Object1[key]` every time has value, you can test

Comment: @BahadorRaghibizadeh - If `Object1 = {b: false}` and `Object2 = {b: 0}` then this takes `Object1`'s `b` value of `false` but not `0`.